# Hide text in comboBox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I've got a WinForms comboBox with the datasouce set to a list of a custom class. I'm displaying these items as colors (based on a property in the class) and would like to *only* display the color (i.e. no text). I'm displaying the items as colors in the dropdown through the DrawItem event, but this doesn't work for the comboBox itself (the part other than the dropdown). I've tried changing the ForeGround Color to Transparent, but that didn't work either. What I'd really like is a `comboBox.DisplayMember = "None";` or something similar.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Edit: So after a bit of fiddling around, I've found one solution: adding a "None" property to the class like this:

```
public string None
{
    get
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

then I can just do the `comboBox.DisplayMember = "None";` like I mentioned before. But I think the question still stands: is there a better way?

Comment: You want to display as empty display member?

Comment: @WillyDavidJr Yes. I want the text of every comboBox item to be empty

Comment: Might be a silly question but did you try to set foreground white instead of transparent?

Comment: Ah tried it... selection color stays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As my "pseudo-solution" seems to be the best solution here, I'll just copy it down here:

Since the items in my comboBox are of a custom class, I added another property to that class:

```
public string None
{
    get
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

and I set the `comboBox.DisplayMember = "None";`. This achieves the result I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

You can make a ComboBox control as a color picker to display and select colors by using `DrawItem` event and also there is a property called `DrawMode` for the ComboBox control which determines whether the Operating System or the code will handle the drawing of the items in the list. This property must be set to `OwnerDrawFixed` using the Properties window in order for the `DrawItem` event implementation to be called.

[image]

```
private void ColorComboBox_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    Graphics g = e.Graphics;
    Rectangle rect = e.Bounds;
    if (e.Index >= 0)
    {
       Color c = Color.FromName(n);
       Brush b = new SolidBrush(c);
       g.DrawString(n, f, Brushes.Black, rect.X, rect.Top);
       g.FillRectangle(b, rect.X, rect.Y + 5, rect.Width -10, rect.Height - 10);
    }
}
```

You can read more about [CodeProject: Color Picker Combo Box](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34332/Color-Picker-Combo-Box)

Comment: Yeah, I've already got that (referenced the same article). But here's my problem: http://i.imgur.com/jC1ufeV.png (I don't want that text visible)